# Babel doesn't put imports on top of scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I am trying to get rid of the below error code:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mywebsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hello",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/me/mywebsite.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "server": "FLASK_ENV=development ENV=SIMU poetry run flask run",
    "compile": "babel --watch front/src/scripts --out-dir front/static/scripts --presets react-app/prod --minified --compact true --no-comments"
  }
}
```

I run `npm run compile` to start compiling my js files, and I get a scripts with a bunch of variables & functions before the imports, hence triggering that warning

Compiled file (not mimified):

```
var _slicedToArray = function () { function sliceIterator(arr, i) { var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"]) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; } return function (arr, i) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) { return arr; } else if (Symbol.iterator in Object(arr)) { return sliceIterator(arr, i); } else { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"); } }; }();

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

function Square(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'button',
    { className: 'square', onClick: props.onClick },
    props.value
  );
}
...
```

If there a way to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: I would assume this is a configuration issue. Maybe you’ll need to specify the scripts should be modules.

Comment: Can you please add `"type": "module",` to your package.json and report back?

Comment: No this didn't change anything.